# Python selenium chromedriver.exe questions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

So I'm wanting to release my python for people to use; And I want to convert it into a .exe using py2exe.

But when using selenium I run into a problem.

```
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
```

if they don't have the same pc name or the file located in the same placed, then of course it will give an error.
I was thinking.. of maybe something like this.

`current_folder_name (example C:\Users\example\Desktop\pythonscript)`

`current_folder_name + "chromedriver.exe"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's common way to place your resources (like chromedriver.exe in this case) in project folder and get path dynamically. For example, your structure:

```
C:/my_project/
    main.py
    chromedriver.exe
```

Then, your code (in main.py):

```
import os

project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
chromedriver_path = os.path.join(project_dir, 'chromedriver.exe')


print(chromedriver_path)  # C:\my_project\chromedriver.exe
```